# iPhone Beginner Question - Hooking Up Actions

Tags: iphone

I'm just starting out with iPhone development, and in my hello world application I'm having a hard time hooking up a view to a controller with actions.  I followed the instructions in the book I'm reading (I believe), but depending on where I run the application the app behaves differently.

-When i command-r from the code, I see only the single button I have on the view taking up the whole window.  When I click the button the action is triggered.

-when I command-r from the interface designer I see the button, label, and textbox lined up correctly.  When I click the button nothing happens.

Anyone know why this is happening/how to fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: What version of xcode are you using?

Comment: @JFoulkes 3.2.5, 64 bit.

Comment: did you save the interface builder file?

Comment: @Andrew - yes I've saved the interface file

Comment: I posted the code onto github, https://github.com/kenmazaika/chapter-2

Answer (score 1):

Launching simulator from interface builder only simulates selected .xib file. You should only do that to test your view design.

If you want to learn the basics about iPhone development I recommend:

NewBoston: http://www.thenewboston.com/?cat=34&pOpen=tutorial

Stanford: http://itunes.stanford.edu/

both are free video tutorials on how to make iPhone apps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you accidentally the whole view.
Seriously. You made one wrong connection. You connected the view outlet of the viewController (aka File's Owner) with the UIButton.

[image]

just delete this connection and connect the view outlet of the File Owner with the "Root"View.

[image]

And you should probably remove almost all connections that trigger btnClicked: too. TouchUpInside from the button is enough.

And you should follow the [objective-c coding style](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php) ([Part II](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000083.php)) and start all Class names with a capital letter. `chapter_2ViewController` should be something like `Chapter2ViewController`.

Comment: this is exactly it.  thank you so much for looking through my project and figuring out the problem.  awesome.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you cannot run an app from interface builder, I may be mistaken.

You should make sure your interface builder file is saved and run the app from within xcode

Comment: you are just running the UI in "simulated" mode, which is generally NOT what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, but is the window size in the simulator different than that in IB?  You might check the control resizing masks and on the sizing tab in IB.